# Apache and Nginx on same disk

Tags: apache2, lamp, nginx, docker

I've been working with LAMP systems on Ubuntu server for a few years, mainly as platform for CMS systems (WordPress, Drupal, etc.).
Now I would like to start using Nginx in a LEMP system.
As I have a machine with a single hd and I cannot add a second one, which is the best solution to have them both on the same machine?

a) Create 2 different partitions to host 2 instances of Ubuntu server (one with LAMP and the other one with LEMP) as a dual boot scenario

b) Use Docker to have 2 different containers for each stack

c) Install LAMP in a single Ubuntu server and creating a virtual machine to run the LEMP stack.

Thanks for any advice!

Best regards

Comment: Option b would be the best

Comment: Option d) is to install Nginx within your current setup. Make it the primary web server (that uses the standard ports 80/433). Change the listen ports of Apache. And setup reverse proxy in Nginx for these virtual hosts that are running under Apache.

Comment: @George Udosen Why option b (Docker) is the best for you? Can you explain further?

Comment: @pa4080 I need to have for example a virtual host running WordPress with Apache and another one running with Nginx.
A setup with Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache would achieve this?,

Comment: Hi, @RobertoJobet, I've threw some answer in order to give you few ideas about that option :)

Comment: Why not install both on the same ubuntu installation, and configure them to listen on different ports? That is the easiest configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As [@George Udosen](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george-udosen) said, within these three options, the option b) is the best. In all other mentioned cases you will need to maintain two OS. In addition the virtual hosts of Apache and Nginx cold share the same DocumentRoot directory and other resources if you need to test the same site under different circumstances (I'm not sure this is possible within Docker, but if you are using the native installation packages it is possible for sure).

If you have the both Apache and Nginx installed at the same time, no mater via Docker's containers or as native packages, you will have the following options:

1) If the both Apache and Nginx use the standard HTTP/S ports (80/443), then you can start/stop the servers depending on which you currently want to use.

2) If one of the servers listens on a custom port, you could access it through that port and in the same time you will be able to access the other on the standard port. In this case the booth servers can be simultaneously active. 
For example let's assume Apache listen on 81 and Nginx listen on 80, then you will be able to access:

- Apache via something like `http://domain.com:81/` and
- Nginx via `http://domain.com/`.

3) Using of reverse proxy is extension of the above case, where one of the servers listen on a custom port (let's say this is Apache) and the other that listen on the standard port (Nginx) is setup as reverse proxy. In this case you will be able to access:

- Nginx via `http://domain.com/` and
- Apache via something like `http://sub.domain.com/` that points to `http://domain.com:81/`.

In addition to this case the non standard port could be denied for public access via the firewall, thus you will need to maintain the security only for the web server that is accessible from outside.